# How to generate utc timestamp using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, datetime-format

How to generate utc timestamp using node.js in the following format:
2015-10-19 14:22:01.
Actual purpose is to generate the current_utc_timestamp using node.js and then to store it in mysql datetime column.

Answer (score 0):

You may use moment.js library in order to do so. Here is the link for it:

http://momentjs.com/docs/